# Nhibernate property Value exception Orchard CMS

Tags: nhibernate, orchardcms

I'm working on a module in orchardCMS and I am trying to save object in database but when I invoke the method create it throws exception saying 
"**NHibernate Property Value exception**"
not-null property references a null or transient value LinksHandling.Models.Links_DM.**ContentItemRecord**

In my db table all columns are nullable but ID column is not nullable and Id Column is Identity so in my object I have values in all attributes and id is set to 0. 
When I go to save this object as below it donot work. However I have made such a function earlier and it was working as well.

```
public bool createLink(Links_DM linkModel)
        {

            var link = _linksRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LinkUrl == linkModel.LinkUrl);
            if (link == null)
            {
                try {                                        
                    _linksRepository.Create(linkModel);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception) 
                {
                    return false;
                }                
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I'm banging my head to figure the issue but could not reach to a solution yet.

here is my **Migration.cs**

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(typeof(Links_DM).Name,
                table => table
                    .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                    .Column<string>("LinkUrl")
                    .Column<string>("LinkName")
                    .Column<int>("PageId")
                    .Column<bool>("IsActive")
                );
```

**Please help** me figure out The issue.
Thanks,
Sohaib